# Is it possible to create a GPO which excludes servers?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Is it possible to create a Group Police Object which only applies to workstations. (Excludes Servers).

If this is possible, can you please point me in the right direction to learning how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Off the top of my head, here are three different ways to do it:

1. You can create an OU for the workstations, move the computer accounts for the workstations to this OU and link the GPO to this OU.
2. You can use Security Filtering to apply the GPO only to your selected workstations.
3. As Greg stated in his answer, you can use a WMI filter to apply it only to computers running a Desktop OS.

Of the three, the third is probably the least effort and the least error prone as it doesn't rely on administrators to manage the placement of computer accounts (method 1) and doesn't require administrators to manage Security Filtering for newly created computer accounts (method 2).

Answer (score 5):

Create a WMI filter for the GPO:

```
SELECT * FROM WIN32_OperatingSystem where ProductType="1"
```